# Issue with Chrome for response type "image" - JSP

Tags: image, jsp, google-chrome, javax.imageio

I am facing the "**net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**" issue only in Chrome browser when rendering PNG image files from a service. I'm invoking an internal service that sends web response as images back to the browser. Since this is an Internal service that is not available outside of my network, I am writing a small utility that acts as a middleware to get the images to people outside the network (say through a public webpage)

I searched extensively in Google and in stackoverflow and found most of the posts are suggesting that the issue is either focused on a specific case or due to Real time protection with some Antivirus software. Disabling the Antivirus on my local machine might solve the issue only on my machine but doesn't solve the issue across all the users.

Below is the JSP code that gets the image from service and renders the response as an image. It is working fine in all the browsers but in chrome.

Please review and suggest if I am doing anything wrong here.

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.awt.*, java.awt.image.*,com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%><%
    String SERVICEURL = "http://testservice";
String sessionValue = request.getParameter("session") != "" ? request.getParameter("session") : "";
String pageValue = request.getParameter("page") != "" ? request.getParameter("page") : "";
if(sessionValue != "" && sessionValue != null) {
    try {
        String RequestURL = SERVICEURL+"/session/"+sessionValue+"/img?page="+pageValue+"&size=322";
        URL u = new URL(RequestURL);
        BufferedImage img = null;
        img = ImageIO.read(u);
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", response.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException timeoutExp) {
        out.println("Timeout");
    }
    catch(Exception exp) {
        out.println(exp);
    }
}
%>
```

When I directly try to access the service with required parameters, it is working just fine in all the browsers. But when trying to do the same using the middleware code above, it throws the error. However, the image is getting rendered in the browser for both cases.

Below are the screenshots for reference

**Invoking the image through the middleware utility:**
[image]

**Invoking the image directly from service:**
[image]

Any suggestions on this would greatly help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be that the problem is caused by `ImageIO.write(..)` invoking `close()` on the stream. Any way, you really should not use `ImageIO` to copy image data like this. Instead, use a forward, or use `RequestDispatcher.forward/include` (depending on use case). If the file isn't available to the servlet engine, you can copy the file byte by byte, to the servlet output stream.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion harald. I'm not using any servlets here. Just a plain jsp page that does the operation. When I tried to flush the content with an output stream, it is just coming as a blank image. Hence I used ImageIO. What is the problem with using ImageIO?

Comment: A JSP is compiled to a Servlet, so yes, you are using servlets (although I would recommend using a plain Servlet, rather than JSP. Beware of whitespace!). :-) The main problem when using `ImageIO` is that you are decoding and then re-encoding the image again. This is quite expensive CPU-wise, plus it may cause quality degradation and/or large file sizes etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Harald. I was able to get a working solution in JSP which clears the "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" issue. Added my solution as an answer below. Please share your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Following Harald's suggestion partially by eliminating the ImageIO package, I derived to the below code which works fine for my requirement.

```
<%@ page language="java"%><%@ page import="java.net.*" %><%@page import="java.io.*" %><%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%><%@page contentType="image/png"%><%
String SERVICEURL = "http://testservice";
String sessionValue = request.getParameter("session") != "" ? request.getParameter("session") : "";
String pageValue = request.getParameter("page") != "" ? request.getParameter("page") : "";
if(sessionValue != "" && sessionValue != null) {
    try {
        String RequestURL = SERVICEURL+"/session/"+sessionValue+"/img?page="+pageValue+"&size=322";
        URL u = new URL(RequestURL);
        URLConnection connection = u.openConnection();
        InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int i;
        byte[] buf = new byte[32 * 1024]; 
        while ((i = inStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, i);
        }
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException timeoutExp) {
        System.out.println(timeoutExp);
    }
    catch(Exception exp) {
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
}
%>
```